# Macro displays 500500 and not 1000

Tags: vba, excel

According to "Excel VBA programming for Dummis" by Walkenbach (page 153) this macro should display 1000.

But when I run it says 500500 in the MsgBox.. hm?

```
Sub AddNumbers()
    Dim Total As Double
    Dim Cnt As Integer
    Total = 0
    For Cnt = 1 To 1000
        Total = Total + Cnt
    Next Cnt
    MsgBox Total
End Sub
```

Comment: Then "Excel VBA programming for Dummis" is wrong

Comment: You are doing a sommation of every number between **1 and 1000**. The answer **is** 500500. (1+2+3+4+5+...)

Comment: Think about it; if `Total = Total + Cnt`, and `Cnt` is 1000 at one point in the loop, and Cnt is also > 0 at another point in the loop, the result _must_ be > 1000, because 1000 + x == y such that x != 0 implies y != 1000. Short answer? Seb's right.

Answer (score 5):

When you are starting out , its easy to get confused !

You might be mistaken `Total` to `Cnt` variable, You are Outputting `Total` (summation result)

The Author explains the same before the code

`When the loop finishes, a MsgBox displays the summed integers`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're summing the numbers from 1 to 1000, which is 500500. Each time you iterate, you add the current number `Cnt`, to the sum.

Answer (score -2):

```
Sub AddNumbers() 
Dim Total As Double 
Dim Cnt As Integer 
Total = 0 
For Cnt = 1 To 1000 
    Total = Cnt
Next Cnt 
MsgBox Total 
End Sub
```

This will display 1000. The sum of all numbers less than a 1000 is not 1000.

Comment: `Total = Cnt` is STILL pretty dumb, please dont loop that. We already know the end answer (1000). You could do `Total += 1` to add up at least. Not just reasign the counter at every loop... You could just do `For Cnt = 1 to 1000 step 1000` and it would still work (with what you wrote).

Comment: This will just output 0. EDIT: Never mind, this post was edited.

Comment: I see I didn't miss just 1 cnt

Comment: ...What's the point of the loop construct here, exactly? You don't do anything with the intermediate value, and you know what the end value will be at the beginning. If you're going to change the code to make the book correct, might as well not half-ass the thing and go full `Total = 1000`.

Comment: @ParthianShot Well I suspect the original loop is **supposed to be** `Total += 1`.. So there is not much more value in the original loop really.

Comment: I don't know, I didn't write the book. Maybe the student is supposed to start off in the debugger and see that he can go through this 1000 times. Maybe this is supposed to be an example they can save. Who cares? This is the information the poster needed. Quit downvoting a post that is more complete and accurate than your own.

Comment: How is looping `Total = Cnt` accurate and complete? You might as well just get rid of the loop and put `Total = 1000`. The loop in your example accomplishes absolutely nothing.

Comment: @cronos2546 `This is the information the poster needed.` The poster wanted to understand why the code didn't do what the book said it would do. He was asking "Why does this code do X rather than Y?" and your answer was "Here's some code that does Y". In what way does that help the OP? It's actually worse than that because, in this case, the loop would just be a confusing distraction to someone still trying to understand loop constructs and their use. `Quit downvoting a post that is more complete and accurate than your own.` I didn't answer. I downvoted because, as an answer, yours is awful.

Comment: @ElGavilan Really? That would have been more efficient eh? The poster posted code and requested a certain output. He also included a reference to training material. Without reference to the actual book, I assumed (more than likely correctly) that this sub was an introduction to For Loops, and that the student probably started off in the debugger with a break point, went through a few examples, then closed, removed the breakpoint, and ran the whole thing. Obviously, direct assignment is "more efficient", but not more suitable to the request and apparent needs of the poster.

Comment: @ParthianShot I answered the question of why he received the sum of the digits "The sum of alll...", and also provided a workable rewrite. Between my answer and the changes in his code, he almost certainly walked away understanding what was causing the mixup.